# can not install docker in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, installation, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I have installed ubuntu minimal in my virtual box (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus")

I tried to install docker as follow:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y \
  apt-transport-https \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  gnupg-agent \
  software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add - && apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
dpkg -S add-apt-repository && add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"

apt-get update
apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io


curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname - 
 s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

but I have an error in this line

```
apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

the error is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use the older docker commands for Ubuntu.

Try this:
If you have Docker already installed with apt-get - uninstall it.

```
sudo apt remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

You need additional packages to allow apt use HTTP repositories. You can have them installed already, but run following to make it clear.

```
sudo apt install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
```

next

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add docker repository to your /etc/apt/source.list

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

next

```
sudo apt update
```

and finally

```
sudo apt install docker-ce
```